# Should I install toolchains in CLion?

Tags: clion

I just installed `CLion` on my Windows, and started a new project, but got some trouble setting up the environment.

When I tried to run the program, it says `CMake executable not found`

And I clicked the blue-colored message Configure, it jumps to Toolchains in settings.

Here, my question is, isn't the toolchain kind of minor things that link to another environment just for ease of use, not a must-do thing?

It says that I should make some toolchains with one of WSL, VS, MinGW, Cygwin. Here, one of these, VS is another IDE, which makes me confusing, because it seems against the purpose of installing CLion that it requires the installation of another IDE.

In summary, what's the purpose of toolchains? Should I install one of those for running C in CLion?

Comment: CLion doesn't come with a compiler. The compiler (and related utilities) are part of the "toolchain" that you need to install.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks! Then isn't there any way I just download the compiler not the entire program? e.g. just download gcc, not heavy WSL..!

Comment: Yes that's what MinGW is for.